# How to get the join ID when using Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a project of my company. However, I am not familiar with Doctrine. I am the old-styled query-guy.

Table-A and Table-B is in one-to-many relation, linking up by "a_id" on Table-B. In the Entity-B, $a_name is specified.

Table-A

```
a_id
a_name
a_attr
```

Table-B

```
b_id
a_id
b_name
b_attr
```

Entity-B

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EntityA")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="a_id")
 * @var Timezone
 */
protected $a_name;
```

Now I am writing a method to get a set of records using IN()

```
/**
 * @param array $ids
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getByIds($ids) {
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT t FROM Entity-B t INDEX BY t.id WHERE t.id IN (:ids)');
}
```

The above line "INDEX" and "WHERE" with the Entity-B ID. How can I "INDEX" and "WHERE" with Entity-A's ID (a_id on Table-B)?

Thanks.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN b.a_name a WHERE a.id ...` ? don't know about index by much

Comment: Actually the ID I want (a_id) is already on table-b. I think a join is not necessary?

Comment: I'm not *quite* certain, if that is possible while still using DQL. But I would hope, that the dbms will just use indexes and optimize out the join ;o/ you can try to implement a native query instead to do this, probably, but it's more work obviously. I'm not quite sure, in which use case you come to have some ids, where you want related entities for, tbh, but I guess there's reasons.

Comment: what error or unexpected behaviour are you getting?

Comment: Not error or unexpected behaviour, but the returning data is not what I want yet. Instead of "SELECT t FROM Entity-B t INDEX BY t.id WHERE t.id IN (:ids)", I want "SELECT t FROM Entity-B t INDEX BY t.a_id WHERE t.a_id IN (:ids)". However, the later DQL won't work, since a_id is used as a "linkage" instead of a "field" in Entity-B.

Comment: Give something like this a try: 'SELECT a.id, t.b_id, t.b_name, t.b_attr FROM Entity-B t LEFT JOIN t.a_name a INDEX BY a.id WHERE a.id IN (:ids)' Let me know how that works for you. In general, when using doctrine try to think more in terms of entities and not so much in terms of tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this or similar for your DQL:

```
SELECT a.a_id, t.b_id, t.b_name, t.b_attr FROM Entity-B t LEFT JOIN t.a_name a INDEX BY a.id WHERE a.a_id IN (:ids)
```

We just add a join to Entity-A, include a.id in the select and then index by a.id.

As we working with entities in doctrine, we need to join the entity to get at its id to then index by it. Also, the naming of your properties within each entity could be simpler and more intuitive. So rather than Entity-A (a) having properties `a_id`, `a_attr`, etc, just use `id`, `attribute`, etc. I assume you just generalised your code for the question and you probably have nicer property names in your project.

Let me know how that DQL works out for you.

Comment: It work. But I am not sure if Doctrine will actually join the table for the data.

Comment: This query is only returning the selected fields. The join is purely there to be able to select the a.a_id field. 

This query is optimised to fetch just the data you need rather than whole entities (tables) which is not efficient data hydration.